# List-packages requiring me to select coding system

Tags: package

Out of nowhere in the past couple days, running `M-x list-packages` has started requiring me to select a coding system because of Chinese(?) characters in the buffer. Selecting the default, utf-8, works just fine. How can I avoid needed to select a coding system when trying to update my packages?

Comment: Does this reproduce for you in `emacs -Q`?

Comment: @Ryan does `(set-default buffer-file-coding-system 'utf-8)` help at all?

Comment: @PythonNut I also had this problem.. I checked my Emacs init file, and yes there was a line with `(set-language-environment "Latin-1")` after commenting this line out, I do not get the question the question any more..